# Refused to display URL in a frame because 'X-Frame-Options' is set to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

I am getting this when trying to access PayPal from my Shopping Cart built using Coffee Cup.
Who needs to provide a solution, PayPal or CoffeeCup (or me) ?? This is the URL I'm trying to access

```
https://www.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=
```

Comment: You really need to provide more information. At what stage in the checkout process are you getting this error? I don't know anything about Coffee Cup, but are you sure you've configured it properly? What have you tried changing? Judging from the error message, you're trying to display something in a frame (which you should really mention in the body of the question) - did Coffee Cup put this frame in, or is it something you added?

Comment: Sorry. This is when I press the "Proceed to check-out" button in the shopping basket. The cart tries to connect to PayPal, message in the status bar says waiting for www.paypal.com and then nothing, it stays on the shopping basket without opening PayPal, so payment can't be made. I haven't added anything, the frame is in the coding from the Coffee Cup software

Comment: Could it be anything to do with using a "masked" domain ?
The registered domain is fluffys.es but this is actually redirected to www.your-aupair.com/fluffy